# Waiting for a condition to be met in node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I wrote a class cotaining the following CoffeScript code:

```
class SomeClass
  # ...lots of other code...

  runner: ->
    process.nextTick =>
      if @some_condition
        @do_something_async()
      @runner()
```

What it is supposed to do is to wait for `@some_condition` to be true. This basically works, however since it really quickly loops through all of this it causes heavy resource usage. How would I do this correctly?

Comment: Find a callback for the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [events](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html) to decouple conditions and code that must run when those conditions are met.

Pattern is:

1. listen for an event and set a listener that would run when the event is fired

   ```
   eventEmitter.on("myEvent", function () {
       console.log("myEvent just happened");
   });
   ```
2. when something in your code can make your condition become true, check for it and fire an event accordingly:

   ```
   doSomething();
   something++;
   if (something > max_something) {
       eventEmitter.emit("myEvent");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a loop that waits for something to be true, just make a callback function and pass that in to the function that is running long and call the callback when the process is done.

Comment: What if I set a limit for something like http requests and the condition is something like currentrequests > maxrequests

Comment: That is not what you asked.